# Calculating median for each column of grouped data

Tags: r, stat

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
 genotype     DIV3     DIV4 ...
 WT           12.4     15.2
 WT           35.4     35.3
 HET          1.3      1.2
 HET          1.5      5.2
```

I want to be able to calculate the median of each column for each group, but I'm not sure the best way to do this in R. I would prefer if I didn't have to call the genotype, as this may not remain constant for other datasets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it amazing that noone has suggested `aggregate` yet, seeing as it is the simple, base R function included for these sorts of tasks. E.g.:

```
aggregate(. ~ genotype, data=dat, FUN=median)

#  genotype DIV3  DIV4
#1      HET  1.4  3.20
#2       WT 23.9 25.25
```

Comment: I would have, but I'm busy watching the World Series.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
apply(df[,-1], 2, function(x) tapply(x, df[,1], mean))
```

Answer (score 2):

I found     ddply     to be the best for this.

```
 medians = ddply(a, .(genotype), numcolwise(median))
```

Comment: Also I thought an answer wasn't suppose to reference genotype

Comment: @Reed, I meant it shouldn't have to reference the specific genotype (e.g.-"WT" or "HET")

Answer (score 2):

data.table version is also good:

```
library(data.table)
ddt[,lapply(.SD, median),by=genotype]
   genotype DIV3  DIV4
1:       WT 23.9 25.25
2:      HET  1.4  3.20
```

Answer (score 0):

In general, I think it's good practice to use `dplyr` solutions instead of `plyr`. It's supposed to be a big improvement in terms of speed and readability. See [this link](http://blog.rstudio.org/2014/01/17/introducing-dplyr/).

For example:

```
require(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(genotype) %>%
  summarize(
    DIV3_median = median(DIV3),
    DIV4_median = median(DIV4)
  )
```

Comment: You could also try something like  `summarise_each(funs(median), contains("DIV"))`